# Can not import dependency of Google-Mobile-Ad in my swift package

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I want to make a package of google-mobile-ads to use on multiple devices.But the issue is I can not import or add the dependency of google-mobile-ads in my swift package.
How I can do this?

Comment: Are you able to provide more information? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples ? Seems to be only CocoaPods supported according to ReadMe, is there a `Package.swift` somewhere for it?